# how to add dependencies to Openshift V3 nodeJs env

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm, dependencies, openshift

I need some help, i'm trying to add mongoose to my openshift v3 env but can't find how.
already try to use package.json.

Edit :

[deploy log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZJJj.png)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-ex",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "projet",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "^2.0.1",
    "ejs": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.16",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.3",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0"
  },
  "engine": {
    "node": "*",
    "npm": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "IP=0.0.0.0 PORT=3030 mocha --timeout 5000 tests/*_test.js"
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm you are using the builtin NodeJS S2I builder. Check the documentation at https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/tree/master/6 to make sure you are setting up everything correctly.

Comment: i'm using git and the web console to deploy and everything is working correctly but i want to add some dependencies and i ignore how to so if you just have some documentation or anythings else. thanks

Comment: I already linked the documentation for the S2I builder in my previous comment.

Comment: thanks for this but it still not clear for me. i just want to add a dependencies i try to execute commande in pod terminal but no success.

Comment: If you add extra things from within the pod they will be lost when the pod is stopped and replaced. You need to make changes in the Git repository containing the application code and ``package.json`` file. You would then trigger a new build of the application from the web console by going to the build configuration.

Comment: yeah i've try to add the dependencies in the package.json file but i'm facing a build error.

Comment: Unfortunately it is rather impossible to guess what that build error is if you don't provide the details of what is in the log output for the S2I build. You could also provide the actual ``package.json`` file so the contents can be validated.

Comment: ok i've added log and package.json in main thread.

Comment: How long does the build run for before it dies? What messages are in the event log under 'Monitoring' tab of the UI? An error during the build saying 'kill' had been run can sometimes be because the amount of memory used during the build was too much. That or the build took too long.